# react css animation when component mounts

Tags: css, reactjs

Here's a fiddle of what I want to do: https://jsfiddle.net/s7s07chm/7/

But I want to do this with react instead of jquery. Basically, I put the `className` of the element in the state, and on `componentDidMount` I update the className to initiate the transition.

But this isn't working. The component is just rendering with the transitioned state. In other words, instead of sliding down, it appears at the bottom from the beginning

Am I doing this wrong?
If so, is there another way to accomplish this?

here's the actual code

```
getInitialState: function() {
  return {
    childClass: 'child'
  };
},
componentDidMount: function() {
  this.setState({
    childClass: 'child low'
  });
},
```

Comment: You might take a look at [ReactCSSTransitionGroup](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the reason that won't work is because your DOM won't be updated until the component is mounted. So the class you're assigning with `getInitialState` will never appear in the DOM, but the one you set with `componentDidMount` will. As Ray mentioned, you should take a look at ReactCSSTransitionGroup.

Answer (score 0):

`componentDidMount` is called after React hands them off to the browser, but the browser might not have finished drawing.

You can however use `requestAnimationFrame` to ensure setState is called after the browser has finished drawing the component.

```
componentDidMount() {
  requestAnimationFrame(() => this.setState({
    childClass: 'child low'
  }))
}
```